# How to make Ansible 'debug' module print a string containing many '\n' as a multiline string?

Tags: string, ansible, multiline, ansible-facts

One of my Ansible variable is defined as

```yaml
- name: prepare the multiline message
  set_fact: 
    report_string: |
      THIS IS A TEST

      state of the machines
      ---------------------

      state of machines of level1: {{ machineslv1_state }}

      state of machines of level2: {{ machineslv2_state }}

      ...


      connection errors
      ---------------------

      connection errors of machines of level1: {{ machineslv1_errconn }}

      connection errors of machines of level2: {{ machineslv2_errconn }}

      ...
      ...
      ...

      END OF THE MESSAGE
```

I would like to print the value of this variable during the playbook execution, so I did this task

```yaml
- name: show the report_string
  debug:
    msg: |
     "{{ report_string }}"
```

However, Ansible prints this as a single-line string having lines joined by '\n'.

Is it possible to print it as multiline string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that the `debug` module is just that...a module for printing information to help you debug things. It's not meant to produce nicely formatted output (write your data to a file using the `template` module if you want that).

That said, you can probably get something closer to what you want if you print a *list of lines* by splitting the data on `\n`:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: prepare the multiline message
    set_fact:
      report_string: |
        THIS IS A TEST

        state of the machines
        ---------------------

        state of machines of level1: ...
        state of machines of level2: ...

        END OF THE MESSAGE

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ report_string.splitlines() }}"
```

This produces:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "THIS IS A TEST",
        "",
        "state of the machines",
        "---------------------",
        "",
        "state of machines of level1: ...",
        "state of machines of level2: ...",
        "",
        "END OF THE MESSAGE"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the end I found more convenient to leave the debug module aside and rely on python instead

```
- name: print the report_string using python
    command: /usr/bin/python
    args:
      stdin: |
        print(" ")
        print("""{{ report_string }}""")
        print(" ")
```